# Fetch Products Grouped By Total Sales?

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have the following MySQL tables:

```
TABLE: Products
----------------------
 id   |   productname
 1030 |   xBox 360
 1031 |   PlayStation 3
 1032 |   iPod Touche

TABLE: Sales
----------------------
 productid | saledate
 1031      | 2010-06-14 06:30:12
 1031      | 2010-06-14 08:54:38
 1030      | 2010-06-14 08:58:10
 1032      | 2010-06-14 10:12:47
```

I want to fetch using php the products i sold today and groupe them by sales number and order by sale date (if possible) , example of Output:

```
 Today's statistics:
 -Playstation 3 (2 sales)
 -Xbox 360 (1 sale)
 -iPod Touche (1 sale)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

david,

something along the lines of (untested):

```
select 
p.productname,
count(s.productid)
from sales s inner join products p
on p.id=s.productid
where s.saledate=curdate()
group by p.productname
```

as i said, untested but 'feels' like it would do what you're after..

jim